# Improving SQL query generated by LINQ to EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have student table and I want to write a Linq query to get multiple counts. The SQL query that Linq generates is too complicated and un-optimized.

Following is definition of my table:

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
[Age] [int] NULL,
```

I need to get one count with students with name = test and one count for students with age > 10.
This is one of the query I have tried:

```
 var sql = from st in school.Students
                          group st by 1 into grp
                          select new
                          {
                              NameCount = grp.Count(k => k.Name == "Test"),
                              AgeCount = grp.Count(k => k.Age > 5)
                          };
```

The SQL query that is generated is:

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Limit1].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Limit1].[C3] AS [C3]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Project2].[C2] AS [C2], 
        (SELECT 
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent3]
            WHERE ([Project2].[C1] = 1) AND ([Extent3].[Age] > 5)) AS [C3]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Distinct1].[C1] AS [C1], 
            (SELECT 
                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                FROM [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent2]
                WHERE ([Distinct1].[C1] = 1) AND (N'Test' = [Extent2].[Name])) AS [C2]
            FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                1 AS [C1]
                FROM [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent1]
            )  AS [Distinct1]
        )  AS [Project2]
    )  AS [Limit1]
```

For me this seems to be complex. This can be achieved by following simple query:

```
select COUNT(CASE WHEN st.Name = 'Test' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NameCount,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN st.Age > 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AgeCount from Student st
```

Is there a way in LINQ with which the SQL query that gets generated will have both the aggregation rather than having it two separate queries joined with nested queries?

Comment: Based on my experience, I can say that EF does not generate optimize query for every scenario. So you here you can invoke the optimized query directly using EF framework and get the result. You can also write a stored procedure too which would cache the Execution plan so you would get faster result.

Comment: Have you actually compared the execution plans to see if the EF query is inefficient? Just because it is longer does not necessarily mean it is worse.

Comment: My testing seems to indicate `COUNT(CASE` in SQL like you have will count all rows, not just rows that return 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my experience with EF6, conditional `Sum` (i.e. `Sum(condition ? 1 : 0)`) is translated much better to SQL than `Count` with predicate (i.e. `Count(condition)`):

```
var query =
    from st in school.Students
    group st by 1 into grp
    select new
    {
        NameCount = grp.Sum(k => k.Name == "Test" ? 1 : 0),
        AgeCount = grp.Sum(k => k.Age > 5 ? 1 : 0)
    };
```

Btw, your SQL example should be using `SUM` as well. In order to utilize the SQL `COUNT` which excludes `NULL`s, it should be `ELSE NULL` or no `ELSE`:

```
select COUNT(CASE WHEN st.Name = 'Test' THEN 1 END) NameCount,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN st.Age > 5 THEN 1 END) AgeCount
    from Student st
```

But there is no equivalent LINQ construct for this, hence no way to let EF6 generate such translation. But IMO the `SUM` is good enough equivalent.

Comment: np. I was not aware of this behavior in EF. I am sure I will be using it at some point soon. (+1 from me).

Comment: @Evk The way it is, it will count both `true` and `false` conditions. `COUNT(1)` is the same as `COUNT(0)` (as well as `COUNT(*)`)

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler query results from not using the unnecessary group by and just querying the table twice in the `select`:

```
var sql = from st in school.Students.Take(1)
          select new {
              NameCount = school.Students.Count(k => k.Name == "Test"),
              AgeCount = school.Students.Count(k => k.Age > 5)
          };
```